# Postfix blocked by firewall

Tags: iptables, postfix

I have set up Postfix on Ubuntu Server 16.04 as satellite system which only listens to localhost and sends outgoing emails to a relay server (via TLS on port 465 and password authentication).
Everything works (I can sent emails) if I don't use the firewall (iptables) but as soon as I activate the firewall, sending of emails times out.

I can't find what to change, any suggestions are welcome.

Here are my settings:

**Postfix main.cf**

```
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic 
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = login
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt 
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated     defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = example.com, $myhostname, localhost
relayhost = [smtps.relay.server]:465
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
```

**iptables.rules**

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
#loop back
-A INPUT  -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT  -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
#APT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 --sport 32768:61000 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 --sport 32768:61000 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 80 --dport 32768:61000 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT  -p udp --sport 53 --dport 32768:61000 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT 
#MAIL
-A INPUT  -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT  -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT  -p tcp --dport 25  -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 25  -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Comment: I do not understand why you have `-A INPUT  -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP`. Try without it. Also, just for testing/debugging, suggest some log lines for INPUT and OUTPUT chains as the last rule before the default DROP so you can observe what is being dropped to gain further insight.

Comment: I removed the -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP line, which didn't help. I looked at the log lines as you suggested and noticed that I had a mistake in the iptables rules. I add an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in the iptables rules. The destination and source ports were mixed. The working rules are:

**iptables.rules:**

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
#loop back
-A INPUT  -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT  -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
#APT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 --sport 32768:61000 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 --sport 32768:61000 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 80 --dport 32768:61000 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT  -p udp --sport 53 --dport 32768:61000 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT 
#MAIL
-A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
#below not required in my use case
#-A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 587 -j ACCEPT
#-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
#-A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 25  -j ACCEPT
#-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25  -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```